# Eclipse: Gluon mobile charm down VideoService - not found

Tags: android, gluon-mobile

I am following [this](http://gluonhq.com/new-gluon-charm-services-part/) page to create a test app with video playback.

`Eclipse` is ready and `Gluon` is installed.
An `SingleView` `Gluon` `Project` was created.
in the `Gluon Mobile Settings` i added Video; i checked if 'video' is also added in the `build.gradle`

so the file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }    
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.11'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonMultimediaApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'video'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

i also "copy and pasted" the `BasicView` from the link above over the default `BasicView`.

NOTE: i had to change the constructor, as the `View`constructor does not accept an `String`...

ALL seems fine, but the VideoService does not get resolved:
[image: error resolving VideoService - other Services get listed]

> NOTE: `Project and External Dependencies` of `Eclipse` shows a list of charm-down-plugins but **NOT** video
>
> NOTE: `gradle dependencies` shows me the version of video service (3.6.0)

What am i missing?

> UPDATE: `gradle clean`, `gradle --refresh-dependencies` does not have any affect (which seems crazy as `gradle dependencies` shows me that VIDEO is a dependency?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RMB on Project -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project